# TypeError when converting datetime object in to UTC

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, timedelta

I have the input date of *2017-08-22T11:32:31+10:00*

I wish to convert this to UTC which would be *2017-08-22+01:32:31*

Code so far

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz


fmt = "%Y-%m-%d+%H:%M:%S"
now_time = datetime('2017-08-22T11:32:31+10:00')
zone = 'UTC'

now_time = now_time.timezone(zone)
print now_time.strftime(fmt)
```

Error

```
now_time = datetime('2017-08-22T11:32:31+10:00')
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: please, read more about `datetime.datetime` objects initialization at [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime)

Comment: That isn't how you construct a datetime object from a string.  You want `datetime.strptime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil.parser` to infer the datetime format when creating your `datetime` object.

```
import dateutil.parser
your_date = dateutil.parser.parse('2017-08-22T11:32:31+10:00')
```

Next, you can use the `.astimezone` function to convert `your_date` to `UTC`:

```
utc_date = your_date.astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(utc_date)
```

Output:

```
2017-08-22 01:32:31+00:00
```